# Remove messages from MSMQ

Tags: msmq

I have program which reads `MSMQ` using GetAllMessages but it does not remove messages from Queue so I have following code; which keep getting same messages. I do not want to process same message again and again. How can I make sure that MSMQ deletes those already received messages or atleast I don't receive it ?

```
while()
{
    Messages[] receivedMessage = queue.GetAllMessages()

    foreach(Message msg in receivedMessage)
    {
        ... Processing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GetAllMessages() gives you a copy of the messages in the queue, but doesn't delete them.

Use any of the [Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90kffs1w.aspx) methods to receive and remove the messages from a queue

Comment: From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.getallmessages.aspx - Remarks: "... GetAllMessages returns a copy of the messages in the queue at the time the method was called". Why are you calling GetAllMessages()?